# Android Fragment Unable to go back

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I have an app that uses fragments with tabs/viewpager

```
[Tab 1][Tab 2][Tab 3]
```

Tab2 has a `ListView` and in the `onClick` method of the `ListView` I am showing a detail view with the following code

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
NextFragment nextFragment = new NextFragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, nextFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

The issue is that in the NextFragment when I use the hardware back button the whole app closes?

Comment: Do you have a `Fragment` *inside* an other `Fragment` or why are you using `getChildFragmentManager()`?

Comment: I removed the getChildFragmentManger() but when I do I can see the old fragment underneath the new one

Comment: Are you using `getSupportFragmentManager()` now? It shouldn't be visible when you add the new fragment to the container in which the `ListView` was placed.

Comment: No, but I tried and it is undefined for the onclick method

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined? Then you are probably not using the support fragment. Try `getFragmentManager()` then.

Comment: I did, and I can see the old fragment underneath the new one

Comment: Hmm this should not happen. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: yep, http://www.philnickl.com/wosm/fragment_error.png

Comment: Is R.id.container also the container for the ListView Fragment?

Comment: R.id.container is the framelayout, and yes it is what the listview frag is in as well

Comment: Hmm this is weird. Sorry I have no idea why this could be happening.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... You should probably show the detail view of the list item in a new activity on a phone, instead of replacing the main view.

Comment: I want to keep the tab bar, etc when I show the detail view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't let you return when back is pressed, but what I've done in my application is the following:

I have overriden the onBackPressed action and created a check that once it is pressed and the user is in the fragment that he wants to return from, just create another fragment transaction to the previous fragment.
I have done so because I needed to update the previous fragment, but I'm sure there is a better way to solve your problem.